# xslt transformation with resorting

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

Heloo, 
I'm writing xslt 1.0 and i have these input

```
<Data>
 <Item>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <Stock_ID>S1</Stock_ID>
   <Stock_amount>5</Stock_amount>
 </Item>
 <Item>
   <ID>2</ID>
   <Stock_ID>S1</Stock_ID>
   <Stock_amount>2</Stock_amount>
 </Item>
 <Item>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <Stock_ID>S2</Stock_ID>
   <Stock_amount>2</Stock_amount>
 </Item>
</Data>
```

And I need output sorted by Item ID, with amount on all stocks. For example:

```
<Data>
  <Item>
    <ID>1<ID>
    <Stock_ID>S1
      <Amount>5</Amount>
    </Stock_ID>
    <Stock_ID>S2
      <Amount>2</Amount>
    </Stock_ID>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ID>2<ID>
    <Stock_ID>S1
      <Amount>5</Amount>
    </Stock_ID>
    <Stock_ID>S2
      <Amount/>
    </Stock_ID>
  </Item>
</Data>
```

Do you have any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Nothing so far.
I do not know how to group items.

Answer (score 0):

To group elements with similar properties/value you have to use [Muenchian Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=muenchian+grouping). It is kind of a workaround for the missing grouping feature of XSLT-1.0 which was then introduced in XSLT-2.0.

Applied to your problem the XSLT code could look like this (I commented the lines as explanation - hope this helps):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- key used for Muenchian grouping -->
  <xsl:key name="ids" match="ID" use="text()" />

  <!-- Match the root element and use Muenchian grouping with the first for-each loop -->
  <xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:copy>                                                   <!-- copy Data element -->
      <xsl:for-each select="Item/ID[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ids',.)[1])]">   <!-- Muenchian Grouping magic -->
        <Item>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />                           <!-- copy ID -->
            <xsl:for-each select="key('ids',.)">                 <!-- loop over similar ID elements -->
                <Stock_ID><xsl:value-of select="../Stock_ID" />  <!-- copy Stock_ID elements content --> 
                    <!-- copy Stock_amount content to new Amount element -->
                    <Amount><xsl:value-of select="../Stock_amount" /></Amount>        
                </Stock_ID>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Item>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>      
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<Data>
    <Item>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Stock_ID>
            S1<Amount>5</Amount>
        </Stock_ID>
        <Stock_ID>
            S2<Amount>2</Amount>
        </Stock_ID>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Stock_ID>
            S1<Amount>2</Amount>
        </Stock_ID>
    </Item>
</Data>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.
Now I have to work on it to a whole.
Thank you very much.